# how to use fb_insights function to import data from facebook using R

Tags: r, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to use fbRads library to import data from facebook using R.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fbRads/fbRads.pdf

I have a valid fbaccount object returned by fb_init function and then I am trying to use exactly the same example mentioned here in the docs:

```
l <- fb_insights(fbacc, date_preset = 'today', level = 'ad')
library(rlist)
list.stack(list.select(l, date_start, date_stop, ad_id, total_actions,
total_unique_actions, total_action_value, impressions, unique_impressions,
social_impressions, unique_social_impressions, clicks, unique_clicks,
social_clicks, unique_social_clicks, spend, frequency, deeplink_clicks,
app_store_clicks, website_clicks, reach, social_reach, ctr, unique_ctr,
cpc, cpm, cpp, cost_per_total_action, cost_per_unique_click,
relevance_score = relevance_score$score))
```

In variable `l`, I get:

```
>print(l)
[[1]]
list()
```

and then

```
>list.stack(list.select(l, date_start, date_stop, ad_id, total_actions,
+                        total_unique_actions, total_action_value, impression .... [TRUNCATED] 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'date_start' not found
```

What seems to be not working here? How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get Fb Ads data using the following command `fb_insights(fbacc, level='ad', time_range = '{"since":"2015-08-01","until":"2016-06-31"}')`, when the time interval wasn't defined by the `time_range` I couldn't get the data.